# Question related to $h$-invariant of a form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. 
Given a form $f \in k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ of degree at least $2$, we define the
Schmidt rank, also known as the $h$-invariant, $h_k(f)$ to be the
least positive integer $h$ such that $f$ can be written identically as
$$
f = u_1 v_1 + ... + u_h v_h,
$$
where each $u_i$ and $v_i$ are forms in $k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ of degree at least $1$.
For example, this comes up in the paper "The density of integer points on homogeneous varieties" by Wolfgang Schmidt.

It can be easily shown that
$$
h-1 \leq h_k(f |_{x_j = 0}) \leq h \leq n.
$$
Let $i_1, ..., i_n$ be the integers $1$ to $n$ in any order. We have by the above inequalities that
$$
h = h_k({f}) \geq h_k({f} |_{x_{i_1}=0}) \geq h_k( {f} |_{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}=0}) \geq ... \geq  h_k( {f} |_{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, ..., x_{i_n} =0}) = 0,
$$
where at each step in the above chain of inequalities, either the value stays the same or decreases by $1$.

I am interested in proving the following:
Let $f \in k[x_1, ..., x_n]$ be a form of degree $d>1$. Suppose positive integers $C$ and $M$ are given,
and $h = h_k(f) > XC$ (where $X$ is sufficiently large with respect to $M$). Suppose also
that $h_k(\mathbf{f}|_{x_j = 0}) = h - 1$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$.
Then there exists $M' = M'(X,M,f)>0$ and $\mathbf{x}' = (x_{i_1}, ..., x_{i_{MC}})$ such that
$$
h_k(\mathbf{f}|_{\mathbf{x}'= \mathbf{0} }) \leq h - M' C.
$$

I am guessing that the statement is true, and I am very interested in proving it but I don't even know where to start at the moment... I would appreciate any assistance! I would also appreciate any input or reference! Thank you very much!

PS I also tagged commutative algebra and algebraic geometry in case there might be a more algebraic/geometric approach to this. Thanks!